# Adding a ToolTip to a enabled/disabled Picture Control in VB.Net?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I need to have a tooltip for an image based on if its enabled or not. Right now I can only make it work with a static tooltip for when it's enabled. How can I make it display a different tooltip if it's disabled?

```
<Button x:Name="Button" Width="21" Height="21" Padding="1,1,2,1" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="DarkGray">
    <Image Source="../../Images/report.png" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
</Button>
```

```
Public Sub SetButtonEnabled(ByVal arg_blnEnabled As Boolean)
    Dim tp As New System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip
    If arg_blnEnabled Then
        Me.IsEnabled = True
        Me.ToolTip = "Reports"
    Else
        Me.IsEnabled = False
        Me.ToolTip = "Please select a Transmittal"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`Style`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/fundamentals/styles-templates-overview#styles) and do it all in XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="Button" Width="21" Height="21" Padding="1,1,2,1" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="DarkGray" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Reports"/>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Please select a Transmittal"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>

    <Image Source="../../Images/report.png" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
</Button>
```

Note: you'll have to remove your existing code for setting `ToolTip`, otherwise it will override this.

Comment: I don't think a button that is not enabled can display a tool tip.

Comment: @Mary Good catch, you need to add `ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"` for that to work. I've updated my answer.